# "Whether" or "Whenever"

Tags: word-choice

I want to say,

> **Whether** it has the high-level privilege or doesn't, this application
>   can work properly.

or maybe it should be

> **Whenever** it has the high-level privilege or doesn't, this application
>   can work properly.

?

Comment: Whether would be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: If you're looking to set up an alternative using ***or***, don't set it off with **whenever**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Whether*** is about something happening (or being true, etc.) or not, so is natural to use in "whether ... or not".

***Whenever*** is not suitable for alternation, for "X or Y", because it is saying "on those occasions when X". It is for things that happen sometimes, but not all the time.